# Extending abstract method with generic parameter (that must extend generic class) in Java

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

Let's say I have a generic builder type:

```
public abstract class Builder<T> {

  public abstract T build();
}
```

Then a Foo class and a builder for it, which extends Builder:

```
public class Foo {
  // stuff
}

public class FooBuilder extends Builder<Foo> {

  public Foo build() {
    return new Foo();
  }
}
```

I also have an abstract, generic Handler type:

```
public abstract class Handler<T> {

  public abstract <U extends Builder<T>> void handle(U builder);
}
```

and finally a FooHandler:

```
public class FooHandler extends Handler<Foo> {

  @Override
  public void handle(FooBuilder builder) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

The issue is that FooHandler's handle() is not recognized as overriding Handler's handle(): `Method does not override method from its superclass`. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the type parameter to the class level

```
abstract class Handler<T, U extends Builder<T>> {
    public abstract void handle(U builder);
}

class FooHandler extends Handler<Foo, FooBuilder> {
    @Override
    public void handle(FooBuilder builder) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that works. Now to figure out why tests fail after this refactor...

Though, does it seem strange that FooHandler is now semantically a Handler not just of Foos but of FooBuilders?

Comment: @dysfunction Nah, I wouldn't put it that way. It's a `FooHandler` _through_ `FooBuilder`s.